# TCPIP : Unable to dispatch packets to server correctly (harware)when sending data for every 100ms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, websocket, tcpclient

I have an application where client app is communicating with hardware. Which is used TCPIP client.

```
await this.stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length, token);
await this.stream.FlushAsync(token);
```

I am trying to send data (15bytes) every 100ms where my hardware timeout is 800ms. I am able to send the data ~1minute, after that I am getting timeout. Whatever the data is sending from client, not able to dispatch to drive.
There is no issue in hardware side (since it is working with another PC based application).

Can any one help me how Stream is skipping my packets b/w communication. ?

Working: Server timeout 5s and sending data for every 200ms.
Expected: Server timeout 800ms and sending data for every xxx?.

Comment: Are you restarting the timer for each call to `WriteAsync`?

Comment: @StephenCleary It is in loop, where thread sleeps for 100ms after sending data hardware.